# Symfony2: How to add and validate a new field in login form

Tags: symfony, validation, recaptcha

I'm using `fosbuserbundle` for handling users,i wish to add a `EWZRecaptcha` field to my login form and validate this field as well, but the authentication process is done by the system which only consider and validate the password and user name.

What I need to do is to inject the `EWZRecaptcha` validator service inside the abstract `authentificationListener` to be able to validate the recaptcha in the `attemptauthentification` method, but am not sure how to do this, it seems complicated because there is noway to override that listener, is there alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

Create new Entity and extend base FosUserBundle `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`and add you custom field.

Then don't forget use this command `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities [YouBundleName]`

Comment: Maxim This has nothing to do with making the field validated while loging in